# Quartz Persistent Jobs mis-fire recovery using JDBC JobStore

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc, quartz-scheduler

I am implementing Quartz scheduler with JDBC JobStore in Spring. I have a use case, where if my application crashes and it has jobs to be executed within time frame between the crash and restart of the scheduler. My approach is to compare nextExecutionTime for all jobs with the current time at startup of the scheduler and if the nextExecutionTime is less than the current time, execute the job.

---

But I have a strong notion that there is a nicer way to get this job done. Either supported by Quartz or already implemented by someone. Can you suggest a better approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the misfire instruction feature do what you want? See the tutorial at [Quartz Tutorial Lesson 4](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-04) and more specifically [Example - Job Misfires](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/Example5)  You probably need to call  `withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow()` when you build your trigger.

Comment: yeah I looked into it, but I am not sure it would be able to catch up with the number of times the job missed to be executed. Like if by the time the scheduler restarts, the job was supposed to be run 3 times, so will the job now run thrice or just once on application resume?

Comment: If you want to run 3 times, you just need "ignore misfires" policy -- withMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires()  See http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/Trigger.html#MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_IGNORE_MISFIRE_POLICY   -- If you want to just run once, do withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed -- http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/CronTrigger.html#MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_ONCE_NOW